# Database location for Microsoft Assessment and Planning Toolkit

Tags: sql-server, inventory

I am running Microsoft Assessment and Planning Toolkit (9.0.135.0) and performing an inventory of my databases but I can't find the "database" of the results.  If I search for the "database" name on my C: drive, I get no results.

Does anyone know where the "database" is located?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found my answer:

```
Option 1:
1. Open SQL Server Management Studio 2012
2. Connect to "(localdb)\maptoolkit" (without the quotes)
2.a: NOTE: You cannot use your computer's host name.  Use (localdb).

Option 2:
1. Go to the following: C:\Users\<your user ID>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MAPToolkit\
```

Here is the link that helped me. [Click Here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b1a61d6-568b-4114-9eee-f380185e175d/cannot-see-the-database-using-by-map-toolkit?forum=map)

Comment: Amazing, Dalai Lama!